# CefSharp.WinForms renders my page two times

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have a WPF application with a browser frame (CefSharp.WinForms).
I have a KeyboardHandler to handle F5 (`browser.Reload();`) and F12 (`browser.ShowDevTools();`).

If I open the dev tools and watch the network tab and reload the page. It looks like the page is rendered two times.

Why does the browser frame requests the server two times? How can I avoid that?

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost:3000");
        _browser.KeyboardHandler = new KeyboardHandler(); // F5, F12
        wfh.Child = _browser;
        
    }
}
```

MainWindows.xaml

```
<WindowsFormsHost 
        x:Name="wfh"></WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: How does your website behave if you repeat the same actions in Chrome?

Comment: What happens if you add the browser as the child before setting the URL?
`_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
wfh.Child = _browser;
_browser.Load("http://localhost:3000");`

Comment: @amaitland If I repeat the same action in Chrome the page is requested one time.

Comment: @Nick If I change the order `_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(); wfh.Child = _browser; _browser.Load("http://localhost:3000");` there is no difference.

Comment: What version are you using?